# Delete old Backup files

Tags: sql-server-2008

I took backups using SQL Server and i want to Delete it 
I tried to do it through Maintenance but , Does not work "it runs normally but does not delete the files 
I tried to Copy it as T/SQL the problem still exists 
I tried many Procedures to do the delete action and again problem exists
the log files on the default location "program files"
the backup files on the G:\ drive 
I have admin privilege on my Account and i tried to delete it manually it works 
so, please advise?

```
EXECUTE master.dbo.xp_delete_file 0,N'G:\Back_Up\Full_Back_Up\',N'BAK',N'2015-06-04T16:44:09',1
```

Comment: Does the user account that Sql Server runs as has enough privileges on the folder you are trying to delete from ?

Comment: yes the user has special privilege on folder and i can delete manually

Comment: what account is the SQL Server service running under? If you're using the default account, it's unlikely to have permissions to the folder that holds your backup file. Should be easy to verify in the event logs.

Comment: i do not understand what you mean ?